# How to guess the random number in smart contract

Tags: solidity

I have listened to alot that generating random numbers based of previous block hash is very dangerous, so I want to test it on my own on two of the smart contract `Dice` & `Roll` . I want `Roll` to predict the random number that `Dice` will generated. How can I do that? (Since `Dice` generates random number from previous block hash). I searched a lot about it but couldn't understand how it can be predictable.

`Dice.sol`:

```
contract Dice {

    uint256 public nonce = 0;
    function TheDice() public {

        bytes32 prevHash = blockhash(block.number - 1);
        bytes32 hash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(prevHash, address(this), nonce));
        uint256 randomNumber = uint256(hash) % 16;
        console.log("random number: ",randomNumber);
        
    }

}
```

`Roll.sol`:

```
contract Roll {

    uint256 public nonce = 0;

    function TheRoll() public {
        bytes32 prevHash = blockhash(block.number - 1);
        bytes32 hash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(prevHash, address(this), nonce));
        uint256 predictedNumber = uint256(hash) % 16;
        nonce++;

        console.log("predicted number: ",predictedNumber);

    }   
}
```

Comment: There's a contradiction in the question title. If the number is truly random, you cannot guess it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be predicted with your code. There are a few things that you need to keep in mind.

You are accessing the previous block hash, which is known to everybody already, hence, is no longer a good source of randomness. But you just one to predict the generated hash in one contract from another contract. Here are the steps:

1. You need to call `TheRoll()` at about the same time `TheDice()` is called, to increase the chances that both transactions will be included in the same block so that the `blockhash(block.number - 1)` they see is the same.
2. Since you want the `TheRoll()` to "predict" what `TheDice()` will generate, you will need to use the address of the `Dice` contract in `TheRoll()` `keccak256` hashing like:

```js
    function TheRoll() public {
        bytes32 prevHash = blockhash(block.number - 1);
        bytes32 hash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(prevHash, theAddressOfTheDiceContract, nonce));
        uint256 predictedNumber = uint256(hash) % 16;

        console.log("predicted number: ",predictedNumber);

   }
```

3. Obviously, you need to make sure that the nonce of `Dice` and `Roll` contracts are the same, so, you should be able to dynamically set the nonce of the `Roll` contract in case the `nonce` of the `Dice` contract is different than the `nonce` of the `Roll` contract.

For example, I refactored your code to be able to "predict" it.

I deployed `Dice` on Rinkeby at: 0x14E96Bb06E2586cf64522212C63E69cef1FBe16b
I deployed `Roll` on Rinkeby at: 0x95a9Ea00C3c83e963b2B01b968d374BEc8E23567

You can see the transactions in `Roll`: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x95a9Ea00C3c83e963b2B01b968d374BEc8E23567

How I set the `diceAddress` after deploying `Dice` and `Roll`.

You can see the transactions in `Dice`:
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x14E96Bb06E2586cf64522212C63E69cef1FBe16b

You can read how both numbers ended up with `12` as the prediction number:

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x95a9Ea00C3c83e963b2B01b968d374BEc8E23567#readContract

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x14E96Bb06E2586cf64522212C63E69cef1FBe16b#readContract

You can call `TheRoll` and `TheDice` one after the other and hope that both will be mined in the same block so the prediction is right:

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x95a9Ea00C3c83e963b2B01b968d374BEc8E23567#writeContract

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x14E96Bb06E2586cf64522212C63E69cef1FBe16b#writeContract

Here is the refactored code:

```js
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.6;

contract Dice {

    uint256 public nonce = 0;
    uint256 public predictedRandomNumber;
    function TheDice() public {
        bytes32 prevHash = blockhash(block.number - 1);
        bytes32 hash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(prevHash, address(this), nonce));
        predictedRandomNumber = uint256(hash) % 16;
        nonce++;
    }

}

contract Roll {

    address public diceAddress;
    uint256 public nonce = 0;
    uint256 public predictedRandomNumber;
    function TheRoll() public {
        bytes32 prevHash = blockhash(block.number - 1);
        bytes32 hash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(prevHash, diceAddress, nonce));
        predictedRandomNumber = uint256(hash) % 16;
        nonce++;
    }

    function setDiceAddress(address _diceAddress) public {
        diceAddress = _diceAddress;
    }

    // This function is used in case `Dice::nonce` changes and `Roll::nonce` is no longer equal to it.
    function setNonce(uint216 _nonce) public {
        nonce = _nonce;
    }

}
```

So, this is not really a "prediction". It's more replicating the logic that the `Dice` contract is using to generate that "random" number (which is not really random).

I hope it helps.

Comment: ohk. Thanks alot Jeremy. It helped me to lern the concept. Thanks